# Does Google Play Store accepts special characters as app name?

Tags: android

My app's name is "@comay"
I'd just like to know if the name's "@" would be a problem 
Thank you very much

Comment: It would be far easier to just try it than to ask here and wait for an answer.

Comment: The thing is, we are still in the designing process of the app and thus do not have it ready. We thought the name was perfect, but never stopped and considered if it was possible

Comment: You can claim a name without having an apk ready.

Answer (score -1):

google play store does accept "@comay" and when you search the app would appear but the issue would arise when you use "@ comay", play store would accept it but when you search for the app it won't appear